# Rake 0.9.1 causing rake:db:migrate to yield deprecation issue, can't downgrade to 0.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, version, dsl, deprecated

I ran a bundle install on my Gemfile recently, and tried to rake:db:migrate. This migration didn't work, and outputs:

```
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method SampleApp::Application#task called at /Users/joshuaballoch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial3/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
```

I read on another post that I should uninstall 0.9.1, but for some reason some gem I have requires 0.9.1 after the uninstall, so I don't know how to fix this. Any suggestions?

FYI my gemfile is:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'



gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '1.0.0.pre2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'



group :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.3.0'
    gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'
    gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
end

group :test do
    gem 'rspec', '2.3.0'
    gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 3.0.8 was released yesterday, and includes ["Fixing Rake 0.9.x integration"](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/6/8/ann-rails-3-0-8-has-been-released). Worth a try.

Comment: yeah i did as you suggested, no more problems. don't understand the error, but the fact that it now works is great. thanks!

Comment: whoops -- still new @ stackoverflow, check mark checked! thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried running it like so: `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

the bundle exec command runs your request in the environment defined by the bundle, so if your global gems differ this may help.

If not, you can add `gem "rake", "0.8.7"` to your gemfile, `bundle install` then try again. Your other dependency should still be met as you aren't removing 0.9.1, just asking bundle exec to use a different version.